# Android Listview OnItemClick Show Dialog

Tags: java, android, listview

In my project I show a dialog when every item of ListView is clicked.
But I get an error after the third position.My code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rapor);
    raporList = new ArrayList<>();
    liste = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);        
    new RaporServis().execute();

    //ListView Select
    liste.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            final CharSequence[] items = {"Görev Ataması Yapıldı", "İşlem Tamamlandı"};
            View curr = parent.getChildAt((int) id);
             //I'm getting an error here.
            TextView c = (TextView) curr.findViewById(R.id.gorevNo);
            String gorevNo = c.getText().toString();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RaporActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("İş Durumu");
            builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    DialogSecimi = items[item].toString();
                }
            });

            builder.setPositiveButton("Kaydet",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.isDurum);
                            tv.setText(DialogSecimi);
                            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#27ae60"));
                            if (DialogSecimi == "Görev Ataması Yapıldı") {
                                isDurumuKodu = "1";
                            } else if (DialogSecimi == "İşlem Tamamlandı") {
                                isDurumuKodu = "3";
                            }

                                Toast.makeText(RaporActivity.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                Toast.makeText(RaporActivity.this, "Error ! Don't Save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        }
                    });
            builder.setNegativeButton("İptal Et",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            Toast.makeText(RaporActivity.this, "İptal Edildi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });


}
```

Error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View
>   android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: use view.findViewById(R.id.gorevNo) instead of View curr = parent.getChildAt((int) id);

Comment: @mudit_sen Unfortunately, I get the same error again

Comment: why you are using getchildAt(id)

Comment: try using position to getChildAt(position)

Comment: Please add getView() method of your list view.

Comment: actually the id is a long value  that is the row id of the item that was clicked.

Comment: I've tried position.But same error

Comment: @mudit_sen you can show a example

Comment: get adapter like adapter = parent.getAdapter() inside onItemClick and get a value from that adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curr is null.Why get data by textView`s text?I think you should get data by adapter,for example,String txt=adapter.get(position).getxxxx.

Because the curr`s data was setted by adapter,so you known the data original.

Comment: I getting textview in listview

Comment: I known.But why by this way?The textview`s data was from adapter original,so you just using adapter can get textview`s data

Comment: My adapter:adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    RaporActivity.this, raporList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"İş Durumu", "Görev No",
                    "Görev Tarihi", "Tamamlama Tarihi", "Atama Yapan Kişi", "Şirket", "Durum", "Açıklama"}, new int[]{R.id.isDurum,
                    R.id.gorevNo, R.id.gorevTarih, R.id.bitTarih, R.id.atamaKisi, R.id.tSirket, R.id.tDurum, R.id.tAciklama});

            liste.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: How to get my adapter?

Comment: This method can get adapter: listView.getAdapter(),if you use  SimpleAdapter,use adapter.getItem(position),then parse to string

Comment: This method can get adapter: listView.getAdapter(),if you use  SimpleAdapter,use adapter.getItem(position),then parse to string.example String data=(String)adapter.getItem(position);

Comment: I getting Error: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: gorevNo = (String) adapter.getItem(position);

Comment: May be need to get data from hash map,but i do not have your code. 
 You can also use the way which get data from textview,anyway this is not a nice way,  {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position,        'final View view' is the textview ,you can do this:TextView c = (TextView)view; If has error,remove the 'final' declare

Answer (score 0):

Edit This part

```
//View curr = parent.getChildAt((int) id);
//I'm getting an error here.
TextView c = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.gorevNo);
```

### or

```
//View curr = parent.getChildAt((int) id);
View curr = parent.getChildAt(position);
//I'm getting an error here.
TextView c = (TextView) curr.findViewById(R.id.gorevNo);
```